# libVLC Adjust Contrast

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I have searched all over to no prevail with this query. On Android tv VLC, I am trying to adjust the contrast in the LibVLC line, but seem to hit a blank.

Any ideas on what might work?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a video filter. From https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

```
Image properties filter (adjust)
      --contrast=<float [0.000000 .. 2.000000]> 
                                 Image contrast (0-2)
          Set the image contrast, between 0 and 2. Defaults to 1.
```

This would go in the libvlc constructor, like so

```
LibVLC = libVLCFactory.getFromOptions(ctx, "--contrast=1.5")
```